# How to define variables only used in certain situations

Tags: python

I have a variable that I define if something is true. I then do some other stuff, and then go back and do more stuff if that condition is true again. For example:

```
def my_func(condition):
  orig_var = 'Hello'
  if condition:
    new_var = 'Goodbye'
    orig_var = orig_var + 's'
  overall = orig_var + ' World!'
  if condition:
    sub_overall = new_var + ' World!'
    overall = overall + sub_overall
  return overall
```

In this situation, my IDE is complaining that new_var may be referenced before use. What's the best way to resolve this? Ignore it, define new_var initially elsewhere, or replicate the line between the two if statements so there's only one if statement (and an else)? Or something else?

Edit: Updated example to make it more representative of my situation.

Comment: You can define new_var as an empty string outside of your function.

Comment: Is it better to do that and have a variable that will never be used, than to just define it only when I know I'll use it?

Comment: What's your IDE?

Comment: You have to initialize the variable before you can use it.

Comment: @HuLuViCa I'm using PyCharm. I can disable it if I want. This is more a question about what the best practice is.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it's probably best to merge your if conditions:

```
def my_func(condition):
  orig_var = 'Hello'
  overall = orig_var + ' World!'
  if condition:
    new_var = 'Goodbye'
    sub_overall = new_var + ' World!'
    overall = overall + sub_overall
  return overall
```

The reason you're getting the error is that you're only assigning `new_var` if the condition is met - but you're doing it in a separate block, so Python can't really tell if that variable will be declared at the point you use it. (It will be, but it can't logically reason that it would be, so it throws an error instead.) Since the conditionals are the same, and since you don't touch `new_var` until you use it, you might as well just move it into the second conditional.

It does seem like you're somewhat complicating things, though, and I suspect that if your condition is `True` you don't really want to return `'Hello World!Goodbye World!'`. So clean code would really do something more akin to this:

```
def f(condition):
    salutation = "Goodbye" if condition else "Hello"
    return f"{salutation} World!"
```

That is, be explicit about what you're returning, and where it might be altered. Determine the custom portion of it in a single location.

Or, if you do want both phrases:

```
def f(condition):
    parting = " Goodbye World!" if condition else ""
    return f"Hello World!{parting}"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. My example was badly written. In my real-world use case, I do indeed touch orig_var in the first if statement. So combining them isn't as simple as that.

Comment: Maybe your update doesn't cover the case you're thinking of, but as it stands the same truth holds: you don't need separate conditionals, at least not to modify `new_var`. That can be handled in the second branch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code needs two `if` statements, one should be enough:

```py
def my_func(condition):
  orig_var = 'Hello'
  overall = orig_var + ' World!'
  if condition:
    new_var = 'Goodbye'
    sub_overall = new_var + ' World!'
    overall = overall + sub_overall
  return overall
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: I've edited my post slightly. My original example wasn't really representative of what I wanted (apologies). I do make a change to orig_var in the first if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What I do in this case is just add the type hint at the beginning 

`new_var: str`